# C++ - Should data passed to a thread be volatile?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, thread-safety, volatile

In Microsoft Visual C++ I can call CreateThread() to create a thread by starting a function with one `void *` parameter. I pass a pointer to a struct as that parameter, and I see a lot of other people do that as well.

My question is if I am passing a pointer to my struct how do I know if the structure members have been actually written to memory before CreateThread() was called? Is there any guarantee they won't be just cached? For example:

```
struct bigapple { string color; int count; } apple;
apple.count = 1;
apple.color = "red";
hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, myfunction, &apple, 0, NULL );

DWORD WINAPI myfunction( void *param )
{
    struct bigapple *myapple = (struct bigapple *)param;

    // how do I know that apple's struct was actually written to memory before CreateThread?
    cout << "Apple count: " << myapple->count << endl; 
}
```

This afternoon while I was reading I saw a lot of Windows code on this website and others that passes in data that is not volatile to a thread, and there doesn't seem to be any memory barrier or anything else. I know C++ or at least older revisions are not "thread aware" so I'm wondering if maybe there's some other reason. My guess would be the compiler sees that I've passed a pointer &apple in a call to CreateThread() so it knows to write out members of `apple` before the call.

Thanks

Comment: Join the thread before you print?!

Comment: This is C, not C++ (`struct bigapple*` ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The relevant Win32 thread functions all take care of the necessary memory barriers. All writes prior to `CreateThread` are visible to the new thread. Obviously the reads in that newly created thread cannot be reordered before the call to `CreateThread`.

`volatile` would not add any extra useful constraints on the compiler, and merely slow down the code. In practice thiw wouldn't be noticeable compared to the cost of creating a new thread, though.

Comment: +1 I don't really need this myself (you and Raymond are more or less primary sources to me :P) but I think the OP might reasonably think [citation needed]...

Comment: What if in the thread I were to assign apple->count = 2. When the thread terminates (via normal return from myfunction) is it guaranteed that 2 was written to the memory location at &apple->count? And furthermore does the calling code "realize" that? For example assume the CreateThread() call is successful and I make the next line `WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);`, and the next `cout << apple->count << endl;`, is it guaranteed that count will be read as 2 and not a cache as 1? Thanks.

Comment: @Mehrdad: See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686355(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @test: The link I just quoted states that Wait functions include appropriate memory barriers.

Comment: Does this apply to all platforms? I have a strong feeling that it does but just in case...

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not be `volatile`. At the same time you are pointing at the valid issue. Detailed operation of the cache is described in the Intel/ARM/etc papers.

Nevertheless you can safely assume that the data **WILL BE WRITTEN**. Otherwise too many things will be broken. Several decades of experience tell that this is so.

If thread scheduler will start thread on the same core, the state of the cache will be fine, otherwise, if not, kernel will flush the cache. Otherwise, nothing will work.

Never use `volatile` for interaction between threads. It is an instruction on how to handle data inside the thread only (use a register copy or always reread, etc).

Comment: Totally agreed with this.  Data coherency hazards exist for short periods of time - perhaps in the 10s of core clock cycles, and often because of CPU optimisation mechanisms such as write-back buffers and cache-prefetch.  SMP architectures in which caches are not shared between cores have extensive cache-snooping arrangements rather than relying on cache flushing on context switch (which is very expensive). 

It's a safe assumption that any sys-call is an implicit memory barrier (possibly even the switch to privileged mode results in this on many architectures).

Comment: @Kirill why do you say never use volatile for interaction between threads?

Comment: Because `volatile` is not intended for this. Its use provides guarantees only for the same thread. If you have `volatile int a; b=a; b=a;`, the compiler is not allowed to omit the second assignment. The var `a` should be red twice. But how many threads will read/write this var at the same time - this is completely not specified. You cannot make any assumptions like that.

Comment: @Kirill thanks for your reply. There's something wrong with my stack overflow notifications because I did not receive your reply as a notification and only caught it by accident so forgive my delay in reply. Do you have any advice on how to handle thread synchronization in Windows, Linux, Mac OSX etc? In Windows I'm currently using critical sections. Mutexes take more resources in Windows but I noticed they're used a lot in Linux.

Comment: @Kirill Also, to follow up on your reply if I'm in a locked area in one thread and I need data to be available in another why not use volatile to make sure the memory is written out (is it guaranteed it will not remain in the cache?) so that when I exit the locked area and some other new thread enters the locked area then it has the updated data? Thanks

Comment: I think in our days after synchronization became part of the library in C++11, it is better to use these functions. Even if they are not perfectly implemented on some platform now, it is a good chance that situation will improve at no cost to you. Critical sect is the right choice for Windows. I am not too familiar with Linux.

Comment: Regarding `volatile`. There are simple chips that do not have any cache at all and it is perfectly clear what each instruction is doing. Volatile is primarily for those architectures. You write the code. You know how it works. In more complex systems with several layers of cache, out of order execution, etc, you have 2 choices: Either look for really **THICK** manual and read it all (on other system similar manual will differ in details) or keep your code as simple and basic as possible.

Comment: It is not possible to give **complete** description of operation of caches that will be true for any modern computer system even in 10-20 pages. At the end of the day, you `take a lock`, after that `update the data`. For the hardware, the `lock` has nothing to do with `data`. This means that you do need some guarantees from the hardware. I do not know any doc that describes these guarantees in clear.

Comment: Last point. Even hardware has bugs. The more you stretch its capabilities, the bigger the chance that you will meet with problems.

Comment: @Kirill Thanks for all the info I will think about what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think optimizer cannot change the order at expense of the correctness. CreateThread() is a function,  parameter binidng for function calls happens *before* the call is made.

Secondly, *volatile* is not very helpful for the purpose you intend. [Check out this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484).

Comment: The first sentence is clearly true. A compiler absolutely may not change the order if that breaks correctness. But what is correct? That may not always be what you expect. For instance, the second sentence shows such a mistaken assumption. The write to `apple.count` is NOT part of parameter binding and may be reordered relative to `&apple`.

Comment: @MSalters ok but then what's the proper way to pass a pointer to a struct as a function parameter and know that the callee will be operating on valid data? Disregarding the threads for a moment, if I do `mystruct.myvar = myval; myfunc(&mystruct);` I was under the impression that myfunc() will always read myvar as myval. Is that correct?

Comment: @test: Disregarding threads, it works because the reordering within a thread will not break thread semantics. The proper way to do so across threads is a memory barrier. These are included in thread synchronization functions. E.g. for Windows, protecting the access to `apple` with a Critical Section will also handle the necessary memory barriers.

Answer (score 0):

You're struggling into a non-problem, and are creating at least other two...

1. Don't worry about the parameter given to CreateThread: if they exist at the time the thread is created they exist until CreateThread returns. And since the thread who creates them does not destroy them, they are also available to the other thread.
2. The problem now becomes who and when they will be destroyed: You create them with `new` so they will exist until a `delete` is called (or until the process terminates: good memory leak!)
3. The process terminate when its main thread terminate (and all other threads will also be terminated as well by the OS!). And there is nothing in your main that makes it to wait for the other thread to complete.
4. Beware when using low level API like `CreateThread` form languages that have thir own library also interfaced with thread. The C-runtime has `_beginthreadex`. It call `CreateThread` and perform also other initialization task for the C++ library you will otherwise miss. Some C (and C++) library function may not work properly without those initializations, that are also required to properly free the runtime resources at termination. Unsing `CreateThread` is like using `malloc` in a context where `delete` is then used to cleanup.

The proper main thread bnehavior should be

```
// create the data
// create the other thread
// // perform othe task
// wait for the oter thread to terminate
// destroy the data
```

What the win32 API documentation don't say clearly is that every `HANDLE` is *waitable*, and become signaled when the associate resource is freed.
To wait for the other thread termination, you main thread will just have to call

```
WaitForSingleObject(hthread,INFINITE);
```

So the main thread will be more properly:

```
{
    data* pdata = new data;
    HANDLE hthread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0,0,yourprocedure, pdata,0,0);
    WaitForSingleObject(htread,INFINITE);
    delete pdata;
}
```

or even

```
{
    data d;
    HANDLE hthread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0,0,yourprocedure, &d,0,0);
    WaitForSingleObject(htread,INFINITE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is valid in another context.
As others have pointed out using a struct and the contents is safe (although access to the data should by synchronized).

However I think that the question is valid if you hav an atomic variable (or a pointer to one) that can be changed outside the thread. My opinion in that case would be that volatile should be used in this case.

**Edit:**
I think the examples on the wiki page are a good explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable