# Guarantees when starting a Boost thread

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-thread

I'am using Boost and Visual Studio 2013 which [don't supports the C++ 11 memory model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#concurrencytable).

Are there any memory guarantees when starting a Boost thread? I look for a guarantee like in the [Java Language Specification 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html):

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

In my case I want to create a (not thread safe) TCP client and than start a receiver thread:

```
struct Connection {
    boost::shared_ptr<TcpClient> client;
};

auto client = boost::shared_ptr<TcpClient>{new TcpClient};
client->setTimeouts(60 * 1000, 60 * 1000);
client->connect(host, port);

auto connection = boost::shared_ptr<Connection>{new Connection};
connection->client = client;

auto receiverThread = boost::shared_ptr<thread>{new thread([&connection]() {
  // can I access the client safely?
  while (connection->client->isConnected()) {
    // do receiving stuff
  }
})};
```

Are the changes to `client`, i. e. timeouts, host and port, visible in the started thread?

Comment: Interesting question. In practice, probably yes, but there's no explicit guarantee that I can find in boost. In the c++11 libraries the release/acquire is a guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The thread didn't exist before-hand so it cannot have "stale" values (e.g. in registers). All writes prior to CreateThread are visible to the new thread.

The underlying OS functions act as implied memory barriers (`CreateThread` e.g.).

See also, e.g.: [C++ - Should data passed to a thread be volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363211/c-should-data-passed-to-a-thread-be-volatile/12364603#12364603)

---

**Side note:** Consider capturing the `connection` shared pointer by value. That's the whole point of shared pointers, to share ownership.

Comment: "The underlying OS functions act as implied memory barriers". Citation?

Comment: @n.m. while I'd also like to see some explicit documentation, I think it is safe to say that `CreateThread` could not perform its function properly without containing at least one memory barrier.  (I suppose you might conceivably run into trouble on hypothetical future platforms in which memory barriers apply only to specific addresses.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston As much sense as it would make, that's not immediately obvious to me, and I can't locate the authoritative documentation to spell that out. The [Synchronization and Multiprocessor Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-and-multiprocessor-issues) page has a short list of "*synchronization functions [that] use the appropriate barriers to ensure memory ordering*" but `CreateThread` is not among them. I wish this answer elaborated some more on the statement and provided some references.

Comment: @dxiv, my reasoning is that the scheduler has to pass information about the new thread to the core that is going to run it, and I can't imagine how that could be done reliably without a memory barrier.  I agree that this is an unsatisfactory argument.  We do know that thread entry is serialized (see the documentation for DllMain) and if this serialization is done with a critical section then that will ensure memory ordering as per the page you linked to.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think we have any guarantee that the loader lock is in fact a critical section.  Whatever synchronization primitive it uses is *probably* equivalent to a critical section as far as memory ordering is concerned, but that's still guesswork on my part.